# PhoneGap 1.5 (Cordova) + ChildBrowser Whitelist Issue

Tags: ios, cordova, childbrowser

I am creating an app using PhoneGap 1.5 (Cordova) and the ChildBrowser Plugin (newest version with naming for PG 1.5 / Cordova.) I use the ChildBrowser plugin to display webpages, PDFs etc. in the app.

In previous versions of PG the Whitelist wasn't as restrictive and would load external resources (css/js etc.) located on remote servers / CDNs called from webpages displayed in the ChildBrowser as long as the main URL was Whitelisted. This appears to have changed and I cannot find a way around it.

Is there a way to allow all URLs to be whitelisted as long as they are loaded through an already whitelisted URL, or is whitelisting every single possible URL the only way?

**EDIT:**
Platform: Target iOS 4.0 ~ 4.3 using XCode 4.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What platform? Android or iOS?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald *facepalm* can't believe I left that out. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have no choice but to whitelist *all* urls in xcode if you want that to work. The calls to external JS/CSS resources are all considered completely separate calls from the browser (they don't know that it's really a child request from the "parent" of the main page). I could be wrong, but pretty sure that's the case.

Comment: After much trial and error I believe that whitelisting all the URLs is the only available option. If anyone comes across a different solution, please post it here. Thanks again Robbo!